# Prevent imageview go below(overlapping) the next element in android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, overlap

I want to prevent imageview(1) from going below edittext(2)(In small screens happening) but i don't want to constraint it with bottom view because it adds margin which is not the case.. I added both barrier and guideline but they function with setting constraints to bottom ..How can i do that? Here is the code of xml layout
[image]

```
<pre><code>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="gr.zag.community.view.auth.AuthenticationViewModel" />
</data>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        tools:context="gr.zag.community.view.auth.LoginFragment">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/login_components"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="login_header,register_btn,register_text,register_line,forgot_password_text,login_btn,login_email_layout,login_email_layout_line,login_password_layout,login_password_layout_line"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.46"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/replay_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/login_header"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_replay" />


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_email_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:color="@color/Gray3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/Gray3"
            android:theme="@style/EditProfileEditTextTheme"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/small_text_bold"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/Gray3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_password_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/login_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/login_header">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="@color/Black"
                android:hint="@string/login_email_hint"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@={viewModel.email}"
                android:textAppearance="@style/caption_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                app:dynamicFontSize="@{true}"
                tools:text="@string/email" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/login_email_layout_line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rebranding_background_ellipse"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Gray3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_email_layout" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_password_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:color="@color/Gray3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/Gray3"
            android:theme="@style/EditProfileEditTextTheme"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:endIconMode="custom"
            app:endIconTint="@color/black"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/small_text_bold"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/Gray3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/login_email_layout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/login_email_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_email_layout_line">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:color="@color/Black"
                android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@={viewModel.password}"
                android:textAppearance="@style/caption_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                app:dynamicFontSize="@{true}"
                tools:text="@string/password_label" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/login_password_layout_line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rebranding_background_ellipse"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Gray3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_password_layout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rebranding_rounded_black"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onLoginClicked(v)}"
            android:paddingHorizontal="32dp"
            android:paddingVertical="14dp"
            android:text="@string/login_button_text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/button_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/CoolGray"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:dynamicFontSize="@{true}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password_layout_line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/login_forgot_password_text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/small_text"
            android:textColor="@color/Gray3"
            android:textColorLink="@color/black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:dynamicFontSize="@{true}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_password_layout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login_password_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_btn"
            tools:text="ξέχασες τον κωδικό σου; πάτα εδώ και όλα καλά!" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/register_line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@color/CoolGray"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/register_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/forgot_password_text"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/login_register_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/caption_bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:dynamicFontSize="@{true}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/register_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rebranding_rounded_black"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/CoolGray"
            android:paddingHorizontal="32dp"
            android:paddingVertical="14dp"
            android:text="@string/login_register_button_text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/button_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/Black2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:dynamicFontSize="@{true}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please post the layout

Comment: I uploaded the code

Comment: Why you don't want to constraints the bottom of the ImageView to the top of the EditText ?

Comment: Because with this constraint it will add a margin and in small screen it will go beyond the screen.I want it to fill up the screen without scrolling